# pyspark returning all rows with column names when using jdbc

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am new to spark, and currently I am working with hive database connecting from a remote server.  I have followed many examples on how to connect spark to a hive jdbc and not many work. One that worked is with the the configuration below, however when fetching a table into spark dataframe, the row values are the column names. Is there something wrong with my query or spark configuration?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('yarn') \
    .appName('Connect-to-Hive') \
    .config('spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled', 'false') \
    .config('parquet.compression', 'SNAPPY') \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

sqlsUrl = 'jdbc:hive2://{username}@{}:10000/{database}'

qryStr = """(SELECT * FROM table_name) as t"""

df_channel = spark.read.format('jdbc')\
    .option('url',sqlsUrl)\
    .option('dbtable', qryStr )\
    .option("user", "{username}") \
    .option("password", "{passw}") \
    .option('UseNativeQuery', 1)\
    .load()
```

Comment: you are using enablehivesupport while you create sparksession so can you just try to see if you can see the tables in the hive database without using jdbc by `spark.catalog.listTables().show()`. Does this shows the table that you are trying to query?

Comment: can you show an example ? your code seems fine. What are you doing to vizualise your data ?

Answer (score 0):

My spark was actually not configured correctly, after configuring correctly the tables are all readable directly without the need to use jdbc